# Zen of Python meaning of "unless you're Dutch"

Tags: meaning, slang, poetry

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>
> Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.

([Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))

why in this poetry it says:

> unless you're Dutch.

Is there any idiom in slang language?

Comment: To add more references and context to this question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148794/47219

Answer (score 9):

The inventor of Python is a Dutch programmer named [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum). "Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch." is probably a reference to the inventor of Perl, [Larry Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall), who is not Dutch. The Perl scripting language is [well known for having many different ways to accomplish a task](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s%5Fmore%5Fthan%5Fone%5Fway%5Fto%5Fdo%5Fit).

Answer (score 3):

I second @CollenV. Since one of the official mottos of Perl is:

> TMTOWTDI (There's More Than One Way To Do It)

it's seems almost certain that "There should be one -- and preferably *only* one --obvious way to do it" is in response to Perl.